# Given php verification that the signature is correct for the specified data using the public key id. What is the ruby equivalent?

Tags: php, ruby, openssl

Given the following PHP method below to verify that a signature is correct for specified data using the public key associated with pub_key_id. See [PHP openssl_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-verify.php). What is the ruby equivalent?. I have the following PHP code snippet:

```
$data = $_POST['posted_data'];
$signature = base64_decode($_POST['signature']);
$public_key_id = openssl_pkey_get_public($public_key);
$verified = openssl_verify($data, $signature, $public_key_id);
openssl_free_key($key_id);

if($verified == 1)
{
    echo "VERIFIED";
}
else if ($verified == 0)
{
    echo "VERIFICATION FAILED";
}
else if ($verified < 0)
{
    echo "ERROR";
}
```

I am trying to write the ruby equivalent of the program? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work for you:

```
signature = Base64.decode64(params["signature"])
sha256    = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new
pub_key   = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(public_key).public_key
pub_key.verify(sha256, signature, params["data"])
```

This will return `true` if the they match, `false` otherwise